# Calculate latitude longitude of intermediate geo point

Tags: ios, geolocation, geo, apple-maps

I have two geo points (-27, 152) and (9, -83) and an intermediate point is (?, 180). I want to calculate Latitude of the intermediate point.

Conditions:
1) On Google Map all three points are on straight line.

So please suggest a formula to calculate it.

//For iOS developers
In actual I am trying to draw polyline on Apple Map in iOS. The polyline does not work when path is crossing 180 meridian.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the slope of the line given the two coordinates that you have.  Then use the slope and one point on the line to figure out the x coordinate (latitude).

Here is a link that will teach you the basic geometry and formula: [Find X-Coordinate of a point on a  line, given another point and slope](https://www.virtualnerd.com/tutorials/?id=Alg1_10_1_3)